# iOS application with two views. It crashes but doesn't give me an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The program is basically just supposed to switch between two views. I'm trying to learn how to make a multi-view app.

```
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

FirstViewController *aView = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
self.firstView = aView;
[window addSubview:firstView.view];

self.window.rootViewController = aView;

return YES;

}
```

I was getting an error saying "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch". I added the line "self.window.rootViewController = aView;" and that error went away. Now, my app will switch from view 1 to view 2 (it always was able to do this) but when trying to switch back it'll crash. The only output I get is "(11db)". It takes me to a screen with a bunch of memory addresses and highlights the following in green:

```
0x10dc09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
```

and it says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address)"

I have no idea how to interpret this output. I followed a series of video guides on youtube to create this program. I did it twice over to make sure I did everything right (I did). The guides are called "xcode tutorial#3 part 1/3 : Multiview Applications" if you'd like to everything that I did.

I'm incredibly confused. Nobody else seems to be having problems.

Comment: How are you switching between views? Is FirstViewController replacing one created in a storyboard? (BTW you don't need the line:[window addSubview:firstView.view]).

Comment: You don't add a subview to the `UIWindow`, setting the `rootViewController` does that for you. I suggest adding your subviews to your `FirstViewController`'s `view`.

Comment: @rdelmar I apologize in advanced. I have no idea how to format my responses. I have two views, each of which has a button. The buttons are connected to methods called 'swapViews', each of which contains this code:      `-(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender{
    
    TestViewsAppDelegate *delegate = (TestViewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [delegate switchViews:self.view toView:firstView.view];
    
    }`

Comment: And what's in the method switchViews?

Comment: I apologize for this formatting... I don't know how to make it look like actual code =/ `-(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender{ TestViewsAppDelegate *delegate = (TestViewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil]; [delegate switchViews:self.view toView:firstView.view]; }`

Comment: You showed that already. But you're calling [delegate switchViews:toView]. What's inside switchViews:toView:?

Comment: @rdelmar I was wrong. This is what the code looks like in switchViews.  `-(void)switchViews:(UIView *)view1 toView:(UIView *)view2{
    
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:view2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    
}`

Comment: This looks like bad code to me. If I'm reading this right, you're taking the view from one view controller and putting it in another, but I'm a little confused. You say you have two views, each with a button -- do you mean two view controllers?

Comment: Yes. Two view controllers. I'm really new to programming in Objective C and I just followed the video tutorial I posted in the OP.

Comment: When I put a break in the program at the "switchViews" method and then manually step through the program, it works perfectly fine. It's only when I try to run the program smoothly that it crashes, which seems really strange to me.

Comment: what is self.firstView ?

Comment: As I know EXC_BAD_ACCESS  means you are trying to access the unavialble pointer. So please try to comment some sentences in which you have release and removefromSuperview.

Comment: I don't have any release statements because I'm using ARC

Comment: @sunny self.firstView is aView, which is a view controller that I created. You can see this in the code that I posted in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Before your Window visible you should set it's root view controller.

Try this :

```
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


FirstViewController *aView = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
self.firstView = aView;

self.window.rootViewController = aView;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

And if you want to saw multiple Views then write condition in your **RootViewController's** **viewDidLoad** and you can redirect to another view.

Still you have any query just tell me.

All the best !!!

Comment: your code seems to be exactly the same as mine. I fail to see any difference. I copy/pasted your code over mine and nothing changed. I tried moving the [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] below where I assigned the rootViewController but that continues to give me an error.

Comment: Unforunately I'm still getting the same error. I don't get any output but it freezes on a page that shows me a lot of memory addresses and the same line of code as above.

Comment: is this code in the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions ???